# С чего мне начать изучение SQL и администрирования Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте, друзья и коллеги.

С чего мне начать? Какую книжку посоветовали бы? В общем понятие есть, но не занимался этим вообще.

Спасибо, новичок.

Comment: sql всмысле mysql?

Comment: Прежде чем начинать, нужно поставить задачу для чего это нужно. Можно программировать, можно админить, можно изучать продукты.

Answer (score 1):

Я SQL учил по книге Уилтона - SQL для начинающих. Очень подробно, куча примеров. Про Оракл сложнее. Есть их фирменные книжки, но некоторые чертовски сложны + Вам необходимо определиться с какой именно версией БД хотите разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

В своё время был авторитетен [Том Кайт](http://asktom.oracle.com)